# for loop stops iterating after 7 iterations in selenium python webdriver - IDE is vs Code

Tags: python, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to create an automation for applying jobs on LinkedIn using Selenium webdriver in python.

Below is my code thus far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


#Defines the bridge between Selenium and Chrome
s = Service ("C:/Users/ugila/Desktop/1/Application/chromedriver.exe")

#To ensure Chrome Browser does not close automatically right after opening the targetted URL
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

#Executes bridge between selenium and chrome while ensuring setting chosen in above option of 
# browser not closing is also executed
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = s, options=options)

#Open below website in the browser that just got opened
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId=3639948433&f_F=it%2Cprjm&f_JT=C&f_TPR=r2592000&geoId=105149290&keywords=IT%20Project%20Manager&location=Ontario%2C%20Canada&refresh=true&sortBy=DD")

#locate Sign in button from opened website
Sign_in_Button = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,'Sign in')

#click sign in button and have sign in page open in the same window
Sign_in_Button.click()

#Username field on sign in page
Username_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'username')

#Enter text in username field on sign in page
Username_field.send_keys("*My Email Address*")

#Password field on sign in page
Password_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password')

#Enter text in password field on sign in page
Password_field.send_keys("*My Password*")

#Login in to Linkedin by entering the username and password provided above
Password_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)

#List of all the posting in filtered job list
All_Listings = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.job-card-container.relative.job-card-list.job-card-container--clickable')
                                   
                                   
#Loop through all the listings in filtered list
for Job in All_Listings:
    print("loop called properly")
    Job.click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Output looks like as below

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\ugila\Desktop\1\Application\Bot.py"
loop called properly
loop called properly
loop called properly
loop called properly
loop called properly
loop called properly
loop called properly

[Done] exited with code=0 in 40.964 seconds
```

which confirms that loop is running properly.

however it only iterates for "7" times and then stops automatically.

I would your help in isolating what the issue is and how can i go about fixing it.

Thank you

I was expecting this for loop to iterate through all the job listings on the page, however loop terminates after 7 iterations.

Comment: There are probably only 7 jobs on the first page.  You'll have to simulate scrolling to get the rest.

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you for your response. However there are more than 20 jobs on first page.

Comment: Well, wait a minute.  You're clicking on all of those links.  Once you click on a link and it goes to another page, the original set of links is gone.  Does it change if you do `for Job in list(All_Listings):`?  And Python's general coding practice is that variables do not start with a capital letter -- only classes.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for responding back, once again. Good catch with variable name. I will rectify that however it doesn't resolve the issue. As far as clicking and page navigation is concerned. Once I click the job listing it does not open in a new page, rather opens the job detail on a webcard within the same page. That is how I am still able to click through the rest of job postings. The issue is not that function is not looping through the postings rather that it only iterates on 7 postings and then terminates with code=0.

Comment: Well, the only reason it would stop is if `All_Listings` signaled that it was through.  If you loop through them without clicking, do you see more?

Comment: @TimRoberts, just checked without clicking. Still iterates only 7 listings. I also though of another scenario may be the entire pages doesn't get loaded and hence the loop exits after the listing that get loaded on page load. To explore that, I loaded the entire page before the loop executes, but still same issue. This is a stubborn problem that I can't wrap my head around.

Comment: For anyone's' ease of reference.

I am attempting to duplicate what was done in below youtube Video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zV508AcOzM0&ab_channel=AppMillers

I am stuck at 18:32 timestamp.